# Import .vue file

Tags: javascript, import, vue.js, vuejs2

I have main.js and app.vue file

main js file inner look like this

```
var a = 1;
import App from './App.vue'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

in App.vue file i want to console.log(a)
return error a is not defined why ? What is wrong ?

Comment: The `a` variable is not in the scope of that component

Comment: The idea of modules is that they encapsulate values defined in them - so that those values are not available elsewhere unless you export them. So you are basically doing things backwards. Imports do not work like includes in languages like PHP, and that's a good thing. Here's a nice resource you can use to learn how ES6 modules work: hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules

Comment: @sbking
I think my code compile look like that
var a = 1;
after App.vue file inner 
So i think a is global variable and after import module must be use a variable

Comment: @MuradSofiyev That is not how ES6 modules work, like I said. Any variables you define within an ES6 module are *locally scoped to that file*. If you want them to be accessible from other files, you have to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) them, and then [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) them in the other file. Or you can attach them as properties on the global object (`window` in browsers, `global` in node.js), but that pretty much negates the benefits of using modules.

Comment: Thabk you so much. I read the link you sent me

Comment: @sbking So sory Do you can  show me after compile my code what it looks like?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev That depends on what compiler you are using.... But you don't have to worry about what your code looks like after it is compiled. The ES6 module and `import`/`export` syntax is well defined and should work the way it was designed to work. See my answer.

Comment: Another small question
console.log(1)
after
import App from './App.vue'
in my App.vue file 
console.log(2)
and when i run code 
my console show 
2
1

Comment: @MuradSofiyev when you import a file, it runs the file's code, but in its own scope (without access to the variables in main.js). So if the console.log(1) is placed *after* the import statement, then it won't run until App.vue's script has run. You could export a function from App.vue, and then call that function from main.js whenever you want to control the timing of execution. I have updated my answer to show you an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146798/discussion-between-sbking-and-murad-sofiyev).

Answer (score 4):

You need to export the variable, and then import it into another file where you want it. The best way to do that would be to put the variable `a` in its own module file. This allows you to avoid using global variables, which pretty much negate the purpose of modules!

a.js:

```
export const a = 'foo'
```

App.vue:

```
<script>
  import { a } from './a.js'
  console.log(a) // foo

  console.log(1)
  export function log3() {
    console.log(3)
  }
</script>
```

main.js:

```
import { log3, default as App } from './App.vue'
console.log(2)
log3()

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})

import { a } from './a.js'
console.log(a) // foo
```

Here is what will be logged to the console:

- 'foo' (from App.vue)
- 1     (from App.vue)
- 2     (from main.js)
- 3     (from main.js calling the function log3 from App.vue)
- 'foo' (from main.js)

Now both App.vue and main.js have access to `a`, because they have explicitly imported it. The fact that App.vue has access to `a` has nothing to do with the fact that `main.js` also has access to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do I guess is define `data` properties insode root instance, and access them as `this.$root.myProperty` from components:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myGlobal: 'Hi there'
  },
  components: {
    'child' : {
      template: `<p>{{ text }}</p>`,
      data: function() {
       return {
          text: this.$root.myGlobal
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Another option - a simple plugin as a central storage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517332/7636961

Comment: Why not just put the "global" variable in its own module and then import it where needed? Why use modules at all if you're just going to use global variables?

Comment: @sbking why use a module for a variable which you can just put into root data object?

Comment: What if another component wants to put a property with the same name onto the root data object?

Comment: @sbking he didn't suggest a global. I don't even know what you mean with  that last comment. Components in Vue don't set properties of other components or the root. Passing it as a prop would be more idiomatic than using $root.

Comment: @BertEvans He uses the name `myGlobal` in his code snippet... Yes, I realize that passing as a prop is more idiomatic, and my wording was incorrect. What I meant was what if another component wanted to use a different $root property with the same name? The properties that exist higher in the hierarchy should not affect the correctness of lower level components.

Comment: @sbking Could you describe a situation for me where the $root could have two properties with the same name? $root is always the Vue instance. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root

Comment: @BertEvans It can't, that's the problem. If developer Bob Smith writes a component that accesses a root property called `foo`, and developer Joe Schmoe writes a component that also accesses a root property called `foo`, they better hope that root property is definitely intended to be used for the exact same purpose in both cases, and isn't just a case of two developers coming up with the same name for two different variables.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `$root` is analogous to a global namespace for the Vue component hierarchy, and that comes with similar problems you would encounter with any global namespace. Why should a variable that is needed for one or two components be automatically exposed to every single component in the entire hierarchy?

Comment: @sbking I understand your line of thought, thank you for clarifying. I think the practice of reaching out of a component to get a value is generally a bad idea. Defining a value on the Vue instance and passing it down to components that need it, however, is standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not defined in your `App` component but directly in `main.js`.

You may want to use a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944273/6320039). (see also [this thread for global variable in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733080/creating-global-variables-in-vuejs))

Comment: Yeah i want use a is global variable and use App.vue file inner

Comment: I did not do this

Comment: This is definitely not a reason for a downvote. To select the question that  you used to resolve your issue, you have to click on the checkmark below voting. Downvoting is for answers that are not relevant to your question.